# Question deleted even it have many answers along with the accepted one

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

The below given question has been deleted by moderators.

I'm aware of a question can delete if there is no answers. But this question,yesterday I answered (got 6 upvotes),and an accepted answer is there and some other answers too around 5.

Still it has been deleted. Any one please share,why it is happened ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838740/find-another-child-in-div/16838827#16838827

Comment: That question is extremely unclear. The OP keeps talking about finding the ID of an element, when he already has it, so it's very unclear what he even means with "find". As a result, the answers are more or less blind guesses. I'm not surprised at all that it ended up closed & deleted.

Comment: @hammar: My head hurts after looking at that question...

Comment: The answers are mostly nonsense/comments. The question is too localized without rework (in which case it would probably end up a duplicate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having many answers doesn't mean the question was any good. In fact, it is often the *worst* questions that end up gathering the most answers. That is exactly what has happened here. Nobody has any idea what the OP is even talking about, so they answer with their best guesses.

I read through them all and I *still* don't know what the OP was looking for.

That question is not going to help anyone in its current form, and I doubt there is anything salvageable that wouldn't be too localized or a duplicate. Deleting it was the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

A [moderator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWnxO.png) can insta delete any question/answer ,OP(!mod) can not delete his question which have an upvoted  answer

And this question is deleted because its  not useful  and unclear  also  useful for further visitors.

Comment: Correction : "OP can not delete his question which has an answer"

Comment: @Lucifer ty .. :)